# Why is &mut moved only when a template type

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm confused about how Rust decides when to move a mutable reference when passing it to a function. Consider the following code:

```rust
fn my_drop<T>(_x: T) {}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 1i32;
    let rm: &mut i32 = &mut a;
    my_drop(rm);
    let value = *rm;
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

As I expect, it fails to compile, because calling `my_drop` moves the value out of `rm` into the function parameter (according to the docs, this is exactly how `drop` is implemented). Since the type of `rm` is `&mut i32`, I expect that `T` is `&mut i32`, and that substituting that in should give exactly the same behaviour:

```rust
fn my_drop2(_x: &mut i32) {}

fn main() {
    let mut a = 1;
    let rm: &mut i32 = &mut a;
    my_drop2(rm);
    let value = *rm;
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

But for some reason this compiles (and runs) without complaint. Why is `rm` not moved out of when using `my_drop2`? And how is it being passed to `my_drop2` without moving out of `rm` and without making a second mutable reference?

Comment: TL;DR: Assigning a reference to another reference is handled specially by the compiler; it "reborrows" as though you'd written `my_drop2(&mut *rm);` but this only happens when the variable being assigned to (a function parameter in this case) is declared to be a reference type. In the generic type it is not explicitly declared to be a reference (it's `T`, not `&mut T`), so no reborrow happens.

Comment: Thanks. The links from the prior question seem to explain most of it. It's a pity it's not explained in the Reference.